# Relation tables in the model yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have 3 tables (`order`, `order_delivery`, `order_types`). Every table has model. For `order` I create gridview. Table `order` has column `order_number`, table `order_delivery` has `order_number` and `order_delivery_code`, table `order_type` `delivery_types_code` and `delivery_types_name`.  In Order I write function `public function getType(){
        return $this->hasOne(OrderDelivery::className(), ['order_id' => 'order_id']);
    }` and in Index write `'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
'type.order_delivery_code'`. And get order_delivery_code for orders in gridview. How can I get delivery_types_name from `order_type` for orders in gridview?

Answer (score 0):

in Order model create relation to OrderDelivery

in OrderDelivery model  create  relation to OrderDeliveryType

in SearchOrder do like this:

```
$query->with(['orderDelivery','orderDelivery.orderDeliveryType'])
```

and in index.php GridView:

```
'attribute'=>'orderDelivery.orderDeliverType.delivery_types_name'
```

Comment: This `$query->with(['orderDelivery','orderDelivery.orderDeliveryType'])` in wich function add?

Comment: in class where You generate ActiveDataProvider for gii crud is ModelSearch, search method